Docker Compose: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused
I want to create a simple spring boot project using the Postgresql database. I am learning docker-compose. So, I make a docker-compose file where I first pull a Postgres image and connect that Postgres to my application jar.
But I am unable to do that. Only postgres-service was running in Docker-compose. Backend_application service was Exited. I did not find out the problem. Because when I ran the application locally, it got the connection with this postgres-serivce.
here is my docker-compose file:
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  application_backend:
    container_name: application_backend
    build: .
    ports:
      - 9091:9090
    environment:
      db-url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
      db-username: admin
      db-password: 1234
    depends_on:
      - db

and here is application docker file:
FROM openjdk:21
EXPOSE 9090
ADD target/demo_e-commerce_app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

and here is application-properties file:
spring.application.name=demo_e-commerce_app

server.port=9090

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=1234

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always

here are some error logs:
application_backend  | 2024-04-27T12:18:48.933Z ERROR 1 --- [demo_e-commerce_app] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
application_backend  |
application_backend  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
application_backend  |  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
application_backend  |  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
application_backend  |  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
application_backend  |  at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
application_backend  |  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
application_backend  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
application_backend  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
application_backend  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
application_backend  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
application_backend  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
application_backend  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
application_backend  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]


How can I fix it?
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.
Updated docker-compose file:
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  application_backend:
    container_name: application_backend
    build: .
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres_container:5432/postgres
    ports:
      - 9091:9090


jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres should be jdbc:postgresql://postgres_container:5432/postgres.

tried with this new one. But got the same error.

If it still says org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. then then the change was not applied. Did you do a docker compose down before the docker compose up?

Ah I think I see what might be going on. You did not bind the url-property of spring to the environment-varialbe db-url. Try changing spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres to spring.datasource.url=${db-url:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres} (same for db-username and db-password)

You also might set an environment variable SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL in your Compose file, which will override the spring.datasource.url setting in application.yml.

thanks everyone. After setting SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL, it works.
